# Looping an Array in jQuery to change CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of elements (their ID's).

```
stage1check("htmlelement1", "htmlelement2", "htmlelement3");
```

These are input fields on a form, How can I change their background colour to red with jQuery? I have tried many times today but I always get an error.

```
 jQuery(stage1check).each(function() {
            console.log("else executed");
            // highlight stage 1 red (required empty fields)    
        });
```

Scratching my head... how do I like `jQuery("#" + stage1check[i]).css("background-color:red;");`for each one?

Comment: You might try the documentation for [*.each*](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function).

Comment: See [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). "This method can take either a property name and value as separate parameters, or a single object of key-value pairs." e.g. `.css('background-color','red')` or `.css({'background-color':'red'})`. Alternatively,  use [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and define a CSS class with `background-color:red;`. Arguably, instead of using IDs, apply the same class to all elements and set `background-color:red` for that class.

Comment: You say `stage1check` is an array, but the first code looks to imply that it's a function...?

Comment: I just wrote the array out my actual array is working @CertainPerformance

Comment: You might want to clarify that then, eg change to `const stage1check = ["htmlelement1", "htmlelement2", "htmlelement3"];`

Comment: I like your thinking @showdev that is quality advice my friend

Comment: how would i loop through the array to add a class @showdev ?

Comment: I'm checking for empty fields > pushing to array > then performing action, the ID's are already part of other functions its just how I've located them in the source

Answer (score 1):

Two issues were mentioned in comments:

1. The syntax for the array is not valid.
2. The syntax for `css()` is not valid.

Also, as mentioned by [msg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4782169/msg), iteration might not be necessary as you can select a jQuery collection of all the IDs and apply the css to that collection.

```js
var stage1check = ["htmlelement1", "htmlelement2", "htmlelement3"];

jQuery('#' + stage1check.join(',#')).css({
  'background-color': 'red'
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="htmlelement1">1</div>
<div id="htmlelement2">2</div>
<div id="htmlelement2b">2b</div>
<div id="htmlelement3">3</div>
```

Alternatively, use a class:

```js
var stage1check = ["htmlelement1", "htmlelement2", "htmlelement3"];
jQuery('#' + stage1check.join(',#')).addClass('selected');
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="htmlelement1">1</div>
<div id="htmlelement2">2</div>
<div id="htmlelement2b">2b</div>
<div id="htmlelement3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a normal JS array, you can just use `forEach()`:

```
yourArray.forEach((element) => {
  jQuery("#" + element).css('background-color','red');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, what does the (element) represent?

Comment: Is it the number of the item in array?

Comment: @Scott It's the current iteration's value from the array. So, `forEach` passes each value from the array to its function, one-by-one, as the variable "element". See [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Also, the `() => {}` format is called an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [*.each*](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) and [*.css*](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value) methods. Note that the parameters for *each* are in a different order to *forEach*.

*.each* isn't needed though if using *.css*:

```js
/*
$('[id^="d"]').each((i, node) =>
  $(node).css('background-color','red')
);
*/

$('[id^="d"]').css('background-color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d0">d0</div>
<div id="d1">d1</div>
<div id="d2">d2</div>
```

You can also do it with plain js:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="d"]').forEach(node =>
  node.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
);
```

```html
<div id="d0">d0</div>
<div id="d1">d1</div>
<div id="d2">d2</div>
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `.each`, `.css` works on collections.